# Is there a way to start and stop all streams in spring cloud streams?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a situation where I need to do some tasks at startup before I start processing streams. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you use functional binding definition, you can call any method before returning the processing function:

```java
@Bean
public Function<String, String> function() {
    init();
    return (x) -> {
        return x;
    };
}

private void init() {
     // initialize ..
}
```

You can find more details about the configuration in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_bindings).